# LINQ query to check if array contains search term

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query that processes a string and I want to change it to deal with an array. How can I do it?

This is the LINQ query at the moment (where `FilteredString` is a string). It works perfectly fine:

```
var xFiltered = Services.Where(x =>
    x.Name.ToUpper().Contains(xFilteredString.ToUpper() ||
    x.Hosts.Select(y => y.Name)
           .Any(y => y.ToUpper().Contains(xFilteredString.ToUpper()))));
```

However, I am struggling to get it to work in this case (the following code doesn't work) where I am checking if an array contains particular value:

```
var xFilteredArray = xFilteredString.Split(',')
var xFilteredArrayToUpper = xFilteredArray.Select(s => s.ToUpperInvariant());

var xFiltered = Services(Where x =>
    x.Name.ToUpper().Any(y => xFilteredArrayToUpper.All(x.Name.Contains) ||
    x.Hosts.Select(y => y.Name)
           .Any(y => y.ToUpper().Contains(xFilteredArrayToUpper.All(x.Name.Contains)))));
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: At this point in the second code block: `x.Hosts.Select(y => y.Name).Any(y => y.ToUpper()` are you wanting to see if `xFilteredArrayToUpper` contains `y.ToUpper()`?

Comment: No I was trying to make it uppercase

Comment: I mean after you call `y.ToUpper()`.. I left out the remainder because it's wrong and unclear of what exactly you want. What is the intent of the questioned line in its entirety? I see you get the names of the Hosts, `.ToUpper()` them, then what?

Comment: I was trying to check if `xFilteredArrayToUpper` can be found in `Hosts` (to uppercase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly then this is how. You want to chech for each item in the `filterArray` if any of it's values is contained in the `x.Name` or `y.Name`:

```
var filterArray = xFilteredString.Split(',')
                                 .Select(s => s.ToUpperInvariant())
                                 .ToList();

var result = Services.Where(x => 
                 filterArray.Any(filter => x.Name.ToUpper().Contains(filter) ||
                 x.Hosts.Any(y => filterArray.Any(filter => y.Name.ToUpper().Contains(filter))));
```

I think a more readable way will be to use the query syntax:

```
var filterArray = xFilteredString.Split(',')
                                 .Select(s => s.ToUpperInvariant())
                                 .ToList();

var result = from x in Services
             let upperName = x.Name.ToUpper() 
             where filterArray.Any(filter => upperName.Contains(filter)) ||
                   x.Hosts.Select(host => host.Name.ToUpper())
                          .Any(host => filterArray.Any(filter => host.Contains(filter)))
             select x;
```

*The use of the `let` and the `Hosts.Select` that I don't have in the method syntax is so the `ToUpper` is performed once for each value checked and not once for each value in the `filterArray` too*

*Also I decided to chain the different operations for creating the `filterArray`. I think it is clearer that way*

Comment: @methuselah - Glad it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Quick question, if I wanted to check hosts => tags => tagName how would I do it?

Comment: So in effect, one host contains many tags which have their own tag names. I want to return the host name if it contains a tag with the matching tag name